# Change DNS Server From Terminal (or script) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, dns

How can I change my DNS server from the Terminal on Mac OS X? [I need this because my DNS is not working correctly with my VPN. Sometimes it's using the DNS for my main connection, and sometimes it's using the DNS specified for the VPN (which it should).]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `scutil` interactively from the terminal. Run `sudo scutil` and run these commands, swapping your DNS servers in where appropriate:

```
> open
> d.init
> d.add ServerAddresses * 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9
> set State:/Network/Service/PRIMARY_SERVICE_ID/DNS
> quit
```

Instead of using `8.8.8.8` and `9.9.9.9` use your DNS servers.

The only problem is this is **not persistent across reboots**. If you want permanent changes, you'll want [ncutil](http://turin.nss.udel.edu/ncutil/). The reason editing `/etc/resolv.conf` isn't sufficient in newer versions of OS X is because configd now uses a database to store information of current settings, which other applications read. Certain applications **will still read** `/etc/resolv.conf` (host for example), although that is not the case for all applications.

Comment: 8.8.8.8 is a valid one, though.  Google's Public DNS.  8.8.4.4 is the secondary.  :-)

Comment: John T, I want these servers to take priority over whatever servers are currently configured. Will it do that?

Comment: It should. You can use `scutil --dns` to confirm.

Comment: This does not seem to work on my Mac OSX 10.7.5 MBP, at least not when done literally. Should I replace anything in the `set State:/Network/Service/PRIMARY_SERVICE_ID/DNS` line or can I use that as it is ? Should the new DNS servers show up in the `scutil --dns` output after the change ?

Comment: @ssc Run `scutil` followed by `> list` to find the key to replace PRIMARY_SERVICE_ID with.

Answer (score 70):

You can use `networksetup`, e.g. for having the Airport connection use [Google's DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns) Servers:

```
networksetup -setdnsservers AirPort 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

You can find out the name of the network service by running `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`. It'll be 'Wi-Fi' probably.

This is the same as if you were to edit the entires in the Network Preference Pane in System Preferences, so it is persistent across reboots.

To reset the list of DNS servers, simply pass `empty`:

```
networksetup -setdnsservers AirPort empty
```

To set DNS automatically for multiple services, you can use a script like this, e.g. to use [1.1.1.1](https://1.1.1.1/)'s servers:

```bash
services=$(networksetup -listallnetworkservices | grep 'Wi-Fi\|Ethernet\|USB')
while read -r service; do
    echo "Setting DNS for $service"
    networksetup -setdnsservers "$service" 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 2606:4700:4700::1111 2606:4700:4700::1001
done <<< "$services"
```

You may be running into a DNS issue on Snow Leopard that occurs when the order DNS servers are queried changes (see question [84144](https://superuser.com/questions/84144/how-is-dns-used-by-individual-processes/84178#84178)))

Comment: Wow, 84144 is the problem I'm having. Still processing all of this.... thank you muchly!

Comment: One note to anyone wanting to remove the DNS, just write "empty" (without the quotes) instead of the DNS: `sudo networksetup -setdnsservers <networkservice> empty`

Comment: It is suggested that after changing the DNS is a good idea to flush caches: `sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache`.

Comment: Could you remove the commas in the general example? I found them misleading as I had to read your other example to see the actual syntax (no commas to separate entries).

Answer (score 29):

I don't have enough points to reply to Chealion's post but to add on to it I'd start with listing the interfaces

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Once you have the interface you'd like to change you can do the below (I'm using the Wi-Fi but you can do any other interface)

```
sudo networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi empty
sudo networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

The first line of the above will empty out the DNS settings then follow it with the DNS servers we'd like to use and finely clear the DNS cache

To verify the DNS change you can do this before and after or simply after

```
scutil --dns | grep 'nameserver\[[0-9]*\]'
```

Comment: Anyone that has stumbled across this page. I have a Gist on GitHub now that should help.

https://gist.github.com/dkittell/34fe7b7422323fba546948b7448933a5

Comment: Thanks David. Can you document an overview (that addresses purpose and/or other helpful context) of what the script (at your above gist) does and why/how/etc?

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh, please take a look at https://www.kittell.net/code/mac-osx-terminal-change-dns/

Answer (score 7):

resolv.conf does not work on OSX anymore.
There is a notice right at the top of that file as follows:

```
#
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
```

Also, `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` does not list all VPN interfaces.

Here is one way to use scutil to target the right interface:
1. Create a file `commands.txt` with your commands for the interactive scutil tool.
e.g. contents for Pulse secure interface in my case:

```
get State:/Network/Service/net.pulsesecure.pulse.nc.main/DNS
d.add ServerAddresses * 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9
set State:/Network/Service/net.pulsesecure.pulse.nc.main/DNS
```

2. Run scutil with the commands piped in. (You need sudo for `set`)

```
sudo scutil < commands.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to resolve certain domains over the vpn you can do this.  Not sure what all versions of macos this works on but it works on Big Sur.  Just replace that IP with that of your nameserver over the vpn and the filename is the domain you want to resolve there.  It seems to work pretty instantaneously, you don't need to HUP anything.

```
sudo bash
mkdir /etc/resolver
cd /etc/resolver
echo 10.10.10.1 > domain.tld
```

Comment: It needs to be `echo "nameserver 10.10.10.1" > domain.tld` but otherwise this is a great solution and still works as of Monterey. You can customise all kinds of behaviour on a per-suffix basis, have a look at `man resolver`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by editing /etc/resolv.conf (remember resolv.conf is reset after reboot), hope it helps - http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/resolver.5.html

Comment: As of older versions of OS X (10.2 and prior), that is the way to go. Not with newer releases though.